# Passing variables to React compiled app from Index.html to controller.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I'm trying to pass variables from index.html to my react app which is compiled and running on express/node server locally. I tried using the window object but node.js don't recognize the window object.

Basically once the app is loaded index.html get user info from query string and send data to userController. See code below

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta content="telephone=no" name="format-detection">
    <meta content="no" name="msapplication-tap-highlight">
    <meta content="user-scalable=no,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,minimum-scale=1,width=device-width" name="viewport">
    <title>App Frontend</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="js/compiledscript.js"></script>
    <script>
        new AppCode({
            root: document.getElementById('root'),
            host: 'http://localhost:3500',
            endpoints: {
                folder: '/api/folder',
                file: '/api/file'
            },
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        });

        //Get iframe data query from parent
        function getParamValue(paramName)
        {
            var url = window.location.search.substring(1); //get rid of "?" in querystring
            var qArray = url.split('&'); //get key-value pairs
            for (var i = 0; i < qArray.length; i++) 
            {
                var pArr = qArray[i].split('='); //split key and value
                if (pArr[0] == paramName) 
                    return pArr[1]; //return value
            }
        }

        var userData = {
            username: getParamValue('username'),
            userid: getParamValue('userid')
        }

        window.userData = userData;
        //console.log(getParamValue('username'));
        //console.log(getParamValue('userid'));


    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

userController.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

const User = mongoose.model('User');
//const users = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'data', 'users.json'), 'utf-8'));

/*
const users = window.userData;
const userid = users.userid;
exports.userid = userid; 
*/


exports.getAll = async (req, res) => {
    const users = await User.find();
    res.json(users);
};


exports.bang = async (req, res, next) => {
    await User.remove();
    next();
};


exports.addNewUser = async (req, res, next) => {
    await User.create(users);
   // next();
};
```

Comment: You could read the query string in `componentDidMount` of your topmost React component instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending the HTML file as static file,

You Can do this solution:

## Solution:

install `ejs` by running the command `npm i ejs` then change your file from `index.html` to `index.ejs`,

add this line to your app
`app.set('view engine', 'ejs');`
and send the file by

```
res.render('index.ejs', {
 // here data to pass
});
```

then you can pass data to `index.ejs` and it will get rendered

you can read the [docs in here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ejs) it will clarify the image more.

#### if you can use server-side rendering

then [redux](https://redux.js.org/recipes/server-rendering) would be the solution

Comment: I'm using const router = express.Router(); inside my index.js route file

Comment: I see this already in the app. app.set('view engine', 'pug');

Comment: if you are setting the view engine to pug why are you not using it?

Comment: I'm coding/updating an existing app so some of the stuff already inside app.js I have no clue of the setup. Learning as I go along. Just need to pass data from index.html to other parts of the app.

Comment: what are you exactly trying to do (what is the app doing) (server-side rendering, client-side rendering)?

Comment: Using node.js to run a compiled React App inside my static public directory. The app is using mongodb to save users information. I'm sending username and userid inside a query string where as the index.html will get the information and past to userController.js. Now that I'm thinking about it, can I insert data from index.html to mongodb. If so I can retreive the info from the userController.js

Comment: '_insert data from index.html to mongodb_' basically sending a request to the server, why not! you can use ajax to send a request but it will be executed at the client browser, if you are trying to send data from index.html to server within the process of sending HTML file I don't suppose this could happen, anyway since you say it's compiled react app it means that you don't have a control over React right?

Comment: Only want to send data no html. I'm guessing this will also be a good approach. Send user data using ajax's to the server and retrieve the data inside the userController.js

Comment: this may work, but I think this is not the best way to implement the thing you are looking to do. but it works.

Comment: I got it working but can't access the data in userController.js It comes back as undefined